# Is Unipolar Mania possible?

Tags: adhd, bipolar-disorder

People who are bipolar fluctuate between mania and depression. It's also possible to just have depression, whether chronic or episodic. Are there conditions like mania without depression not due to drugs?

I think I've seen this: [Hypomania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypomania). Hyperactivity, especially in speech, irritability, etc, yet not so severe as full blown mania. Can such a condition be chronic? Is it possible as a standalone condition, or maybe as a combination of other disorders? For example, could ADHD be severe enough to effectively become a chronic hypomania?

Comment: You would just call this "mania", and probably the question you want to ask is "does mania occur chronically outside bipolar disorder".

Comment: Also see: [How do we know bipolar is one illness rather than two comorbid illnesses?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/12172/7001)